# How to make a summarized group by using SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services

I created a SQL stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [stored procedure name]
    (@Location [varchar](255),
     @start_date datetime,
     @end_date datetime)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT id, location, name, begin_date, age, career, phone_number
    FROM information
    WHERE [begin_date] BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date 
    AND [location] = @Location
END
```

And there are different groups in location: Shanghai, New York, Toronto, Sydney, Tokyo. But now I would like to have one more category: All. This category will display all locations. So I can use it in SSRS.

What I wrote:

```
select 1 as sort_order, 'All' as location
union
select distinct 2 as sort_order, location from information
order by sort_order, location
```

But this will only return a dropdown list of:

```
"All", "Shanghai", "New York", "Toronto", "Sydney", "Tokyo"
```

When I click on Shanghai, New York, Toronto, Sydney, Tokyo, it works fine and display corresponding data. But when I click on "All", there is no data showing up. How can I alter my code to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to take `All` into account:

```
and ([location] = @Location or @location = 'All')
```

Often, a `NULL` value is used, to avoid conflict with valid values:

```
and ([location] = @Location or @location is null)
```

Comment: Oh, it works. I'm surprised. But you haven't set "All" to anything. Is it like something pre-defined in SQL?

Comment: In his first example, if  the location parameter = 'All',  he's just not filtering by location.

Comment: oh I see. Thx! This is very smart.

Comment: Oh by the way, how can I make 'All' to be my default location?

Comment: @VivHuang for your location parameter on the report.. set the default for it to be ="All"

Comment: @Harry ok let me try